# Can we handle lenghth of an javascript array using between

Tags: javascript

I will have data in this format from the DB:

> (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) DD/mm/yyyy hh:MM:SS

From the Date Picker Text Input components , the selction can be made between 1 to 6 Months.

If the difference betweeen FromDate and ToDate is 1 Day then only show hours:

```
tickFormatter: function(n)
{
   var date = '28/05/2011 12:05'; // For rampl
   var elem = date.split('');
   hours = elem[0];
   return hours ; 
}
```

For 1 Day there will be 24 Points

```
if (Datearray.length<=24)
{
   turn Datearray.length ; 
}
```

My question is if the difrence is between than 3 days, I will show only dates.

So typically it would be the Database result array is 72.

Can we handle in this way?

```
if (Datearray.length between 70 and 74) {
    // Then show dates.
}
```

Comment: What happend when you handle like this ? any error?

Comment: http://ditio.net/2010/05/02/javascript-date-difference-calculation/

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to "do things the hard way". Maybe @zod's link can put you on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

There is no between operator in javascript. You will need to do 2 comparisons and join them with an && (and) operator.

```
if (Datearray.length >= 70 && Datearray.length <=74) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: +1 even though the OP said *between*, not *inclusive* so `>` and `<` not `>=` and `<=`. But that might be a mistake and inclusive might have been intended.

Comment: The SQL BETWEEN Operator (which is what he asked for) is inclusive: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225976(v=sql.80).aspx